# VKNet (vknet). Как загрузить несколько фотографий на сервер ВК (vk market)?

Tags: c#, vknet

Вот пример с сайта разработчиков vknet (https://vknet.github.io/vk/photos/getMarketUploadServer/)
Это работает, одну фотографию я загружаю. Но вот как загрузить несколько - я не знаю :(
Заранее благодарю!

```
// Получить адрес сервера для загрузки.
var uploadServer = Api.Photo.GetMarketUploadServer(123, true, 5, 5, 200);
// Загрузить фотографию.
var wc = new WebClient();
var responseImg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(uploadServer.UploadUrl, @"test.jpg"));
// Сохранить загруженную фотографию
var photo = Api.Photo.SaveMarketPhoto(123, responseImg);
Api.Market.Add(new MarketProductParams
{
    OwnerId = -123,
    CategoryId = 200,
    MainPhotoId = photo.FirstOrDefault().Id.Value,
    Deleted = false,
    Name = "Телефон",
    Description = "Описание товара",
    Price = 10000
});
```

Comment: `WebClient` является синхронным и устаревшим, чтобы грузить с помощью него файлы, придется либо загружать их по очереди, либо использовать многопоточку, что в случае с IO операциями не имеет никакого смысла. Используйте `HttpClient` для загрузки файлов на сервер. Несколько файлов можно загрузить например в цикле, пусть даже в асинхронном. Если вопрос про API, то уточните в чем именно вопрос, если не в самом процессе загрузки файла на CDN. Есть еще такой методы https://vknet.github.io/vk/photos/getMarketAlbumUploadServer/ и https://dev.vk.com/method/photos.saveMarketAlbumPhoto

Comment: Доброе время суток, aepot!
Спасибо за ответ!

getMarketAlbumUploadServer и saveMarketAlbumPhoto - это для подборок в магазине ВК.

Comment: responseImg получает информацию о загруженном файле на сервер ВК
потом responseImg передаётся в SaveMarketPhoto для сохранения 
У меня затык в следующем - как мне соединить несколько responseImg в один... ?

если использовать этот код несколько раз ...
var responseImg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(uploadServer.UploadUrl, @"test.jpg"));
var photo = Api.Photo.SaveMarketPhoto(123, responseImg);
... то перезаписуется одно и тот же фото  но не добавляется

Comment: Подскажите как реализовать загрузку файлов ( multipart/form-data ) на сервер одним потоком ?
У меня есть код на PHP  - как реализовать его на .net ?

$curl_images['file1')] = curl_file_create($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vk/img/'.$rnd_file_name,'image/jpeg', $rnd_file_name);
$ch = curl_init($getMarketUploadServer['upload_url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_images);
$img_attach = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412463/373567